# Where to put the author in a markdown quote?

Tags: markdown

If I want to quote a person using markdown, where should I put the author?

This is readme-related, I hope therefore that it's close enough to what Stackoverflow is all about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Citing the author of a blockquote using Markdown Syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002120/citing-the-author-of-a-blockquote-using-markdown-syntax)

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Markdown for Bitbucket, and ended up using a solution like:

```
> "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about,
> the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at
> efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and 
> maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say
> about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet 
> we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."
> 
> — Donald Knuth
```